# Why does jQuery enter the success function when I have a cross-domain error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

When I execute the following code from localhost, for some reason jQuery enters the success function call, when really, I am getting a cross-domain issue (CORS isn't enabled on thirdpartydomain.com and I can't change it). The value of `result` is `undefined`.

```
var statusCheckUrl = "https://www.thirdpartydomain.com/webchat/live?action=avail";
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        url: statusCheckUrl,
        success: function(result) {
           console.log("result is: "+result);
           eval(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
            unavailable();
        },
        timeout: 2000,
        cache: false
    });
```

I would have thought that the error function would be executed in this instance. Can you tell me why it's entering the success function call?

I am using jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: because your datatype is script

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js